# Ionization process

Tags: interactions, ionization-energy

Is it possible that ions can be doubly or more charged in the ionization process? like if we have 22keV energy photon then can this much energy photon ionize the Ar atom twice ionize and more? because ionisation energy of the Ar atom is, lets say, 30eV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a single photon can be absorbed by an atom to produce an $M^{2+}$ ion. The probability for this is usually low but it can be experimentally observed, and indeed there have been papers observing it in [Xenon](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/22/7/003) and in [other noble gases](https://opg.optica.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-8-7-368&id=63899).

We tend to think of the atomic orbitals as separate e.g. a photon could be absorbed by a 1s electron, or a 3d electron to produce a singly charged $M^+$ ion, but it couldn't be absorbed by two orbitals at once. However this is only approximately true.

In a polyelectronic atom the electrons repel each other and this mixes up the orbitals so that there are no separate 1s, 2s, etc orbitals. Instead there are *whole atom* wavefunctions that describe all the electrons. This mixing together of the orbitals due to interactions between the electrons is known as [electron correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_correlation).

So there is a single ground state wavefunction and there are various $M^{2+}$ wavefunctions, and a single photon can produce a transition between these different *whole atom* wavefunctions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, single atom can be ionized multiple times in a row. So that your given total energy is enough to make series of ionizations in a pair of neutral Argon atoms, that is :
$$ \sum E_{~22keV} \to Ar^{18+} + Ar^{16+} \tag 1$$

According to Argon atom [ionization energies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energies_of_the_elements_(data_page)), (CRC field shows ionization energies in $\text {eV}$).

**However**, as electron absorbs incident photon completely, in the process of ionization,- you can't perform (1) reaction just with single photon. For that to happen, you need at least $34$ *separate* photons. If you'll just shot single $22~keV$ photon at the Argon neutral atom, then likely reaction,

$$ \gamma_{_{22\,000~eV}} \to e^- + K_{21984~eV} \tag 2,$$

Term $K$ marks residual kinetic energy which will be carried by emitted free electron after 1-rst ionization.

My last paragraph was referring to photoionization. In case of strong electromagnetic fields, emitted electron from ionization process, can produce [electron avalanche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_avalanche). Whereby electron's kinetic energy such high so that while in the path of travel it may collide with other Argon/medium atoms and ionize them by the impact ionization event.